# Characters that need to be escaped in an Objective-C NSString object

Tags: objective-c

Want to know the whole character set whose characters have to be escaped in an Objective-C NSString object in order to be recognized properly, e.g. `"` has to be escaped as `\"`, as in

```
NSString *temporaryString = @"That book is dubbed as \"the little book\".";
```

Is the character set same with the one in `C` language `char *` string?

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only characters that have to be escaped are the `"` (double-quote) and `\` (backslash) characters.

There are other special character literals such as `\n` that have special meaning but those are really a separate issue.

Objective-C `NSString` values use the same set of special character literals as C.

Comment: @neilb The `%` characters does not need to be escaped in an `NSString` literal unless you are talking about in a format string. But the question isn't about format strings.