# Regular Expression, Unknown escape squence '\s'

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex

I'm looking to strip the whitespace out of the beginning and end of my string. I'm using the following regular expression.

```
NSString *pattern = @"(?:^\s+|\s+$)";
```

This is coming up with an error that `\s` is not a valid escape character. Replacing this with `\\s` appears to work but what I'd like to know is why? I thought `\s` is a whitespace charecter and `\\s` would give me a literal string of '\s'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in thinking `\s` is the space sequence in regular expressions however you have to think about what context you're writing this regex in.

You're writing a regular expression inside of a string which means you need to escape certain character such as `\` otherwise you would be able to write `\n` and it would literally be interpreted as a newline. Example of what it would interpret the string `@"{\n}"` as:

```
"{
}"
```

To sum this up, you just need to escape `\` so that it doesn't try to escape `s` (which `\s` doesn't mean anything in the context of a string as xcode is correctly reporting to you).

tl;dr escape `\` in strings so they get interpreted properly in the regular expressions.

[Another answer that talks about escape sequences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682655/characters-that-need-to-be-escaped-in-an-objective-c-nsstring-object)

Answer (score 4):

`\s` (not `/s`) is the regex escape for a whitespace character.

But in an `NSString` literal (and C string literals), you need to escape backslashes with a backslash to prevent the backslash from being used as a character escape sequence.

This is why you need `\\s` in your `NSString`. Otherwise the compiler thinks you are trying to use the escape character `\s` which isn't a valid C/Objective-C escape character (valid example are `\n`, `\t`, etc.).